# Transition to route's action from Ember object

Tags: object, ember.js, routes, transition

I am fairly new to ember. I have an existing Ember App and i need to implement a functionality in it. I have a Ember Object as below

```
`import Ember from 'ember'`

CallService = Ember.Object.extend

 ... other code here

 _updateConnectedLeadId: (->
    console.log "Do i get here??"

    **pass the route action here**

  ).observes('some_other_here')
`export default CallService`
```

Unfortunately, i couldn't put the whole code here.

My route looks like

```
ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  actions:
    showLead: ->
      console.log data
      console.log "did i get here?"
      @transitionTo('dashboard')

`export default ApplicationRoute`
```

I tried using `@send('showLead')`, `@sendAction('showLead')` in my method but no luck.

My main intention is to make a transition once the `console.log "Do i get here??"` is displayed. I am not sure if i am on the right way here.

I also tried using `@transitionTo('dashboard')` and `@transitionToRote('dashboard')` directly but it throws me errors.

I have been stuck for a day on this now and i am clueless.

I'll be grateful for any guidance and help. Thanks

Comment: maybe you can upload your code here, https://ember-twiddle.com/

Comment: @amaia, i really don't think that'll be necessary. I have provided the important code that is relevant. I'll wait for any answer asking for more of it. Thanks for the link though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the problem that you are trying to trigger a route action or trigger a transition from within an `Ember.Object`, named call service. The code you create is unclear about where your custom object is being created; where the observer is triggered due to a change to object's property update, and so on.

Nevertheless, I tried to provide a working [example](https://ember-twiddle.com/9104dbdf89386ed6c89386c33e4bc6e7?openFiles=my-object.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs&route=%2Fmy-route) for you. If you open the twiddle, you will see that I created a `my-object` instance within `index.js` route and pass it as `model` to `my-component`. When you click the button within `my-component.hbs`. The `my-object` instances `dummyVariable` is toggled and the observer within `my-object` executes. The tricky part here is that I passed `index` route itself as `ownerRoute` property to `my-object` instance; so that I can trigger the `index` route's `dummyAction` from within `my-object.js` with

```
ownerRoute.send('dummyAction');
```

so that related action executes and transition to `my-route` is performed. Although, I believe this might solve your question; I am not quite happy about the design. I do not think, it is a good way for Ember.Objects to know about routes, actions, controllers, etc. I believe the proper way is observing object's relevant properties from within this constructs and perform necessary actions by their own. Moreover, you might consider creating a `service` instead of an object and inject the service directly to your route instead of creating an instance of your class extending `Ember.Object`. If you have to extend from `Ember.Object` you can just inject relevant route, controller, etc to the instances of that particular object class by using an [instance-initializer](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/applications/initializers/) if you need.

Anyway, please take a look at the twiddle and ask more if you need to. I will be happy to help if I can.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to create a working demo. I'm not very much aware about the standards but i guess i agree with you on "I do not think, it is a good way for Ember.Objects to know about routes, actions, controllers, etc."

Would you please explain your point " I believe the proper way is observing object's relevant properties from within this constructs and perform necessary actions by their own. Moreover, you might consider creating a service instead of an object and inject the service directly to your route instead of creating an instance of your class extending Ember.Object"

Comment: @Aakanksha i will explain it more when I have more time for sure.

Comment: I appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: I believe when you extend `Ember.Object`, this class should better encapsulate its own behavior (functions) and data (properties). It should be reusable, you might consider re-using it in different modules, applications, etc. On the other hand, an Ember router, controller is mostly specific to that application. So, it is better for a class extending Ember.Object to work independently without knowing about routes, controllers, etc. On the other hand, routes/controllers will most likely create the instances of that specific class; hence can observe properties of instances they created or know.

Comment: In fact there is not a standard to follow related with the case you asked about. This is my own experience about ember and somebody else should suggest something different; however when a class needs to know about a specific router, controller, etc. I prefer to extend from `Ember.Service` instead of `Ember.Object`. Services are singletons and you do not need to create an instance to use them. Moreover, routes/controllers (other instances managed by Ember infrastructure) should be injected directly to the service and of course a service should be injected to other classes managed by ember.

Comment: @Aakanksha I appended the followup discussion as comments because; it is not inherently related with the question you asked; but it is something more detail about the answer I have provided. I believe I have answered your question and provided a valid answer and I should appreciate if you can upvote and accept the answer if there is not a direct followup question that you would like to ask. My best regards.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Your twiddle helped me a lot to understand the concept. I got the desired result by making a few tweaks to your code and adding some to it. About accepting the answer, i'll do it right away. Thanks a ton :)